# Hello, my while loops aren't responding to their set conditions once the value is updated. the code just keeps going until it reaches the end

Tags: c++, function, while-loop, fstream, iostream

***Link to Code: https://onlinegdb.com/B1DsFDa8D***

Hello, my while loops aren't responding to their set conditions once the value is updated. the code just keeps going until it reaches the end. If you run the code you'll see what I'm talking about(in fact it is necessary that you do so). When the value of the parameter is updated the value does add up and changes. When I print out the value of it at the end of the code it does in fact register as the number that should be assigned to it throughout the loop but the loop just doesn't do anything when it should be stopped. Basically my problem might be an infinite loop. the only thing that counters it is a "return 0;" at the end of the loop.

My professor gave specific instructions: Create a hangman game. The game usually involves one player guessing letters to a secret word. Bad guesses cause the picture of a hangman to be drawn one segment at a time. Once there are 7 bad guesses, the hangman picture has been drawn and the player guessing loses the game. In your game, seven bad answers to any of 16 multiple choice questions will result in a lost game.
Program 1 Writes 16 questions to a file called “infile.txt”
Program 2 reads “infile.txt” and uses the questions for the hangman game

Use a boolean value-returning function called "is_hung". This function takes an integer parameter called "num_errors". This parameter is tested using an "if-else" statement to determine how much of the hangman to display to the screen based on the number of wrong answers.

The entire hangman can be displayed by the code segment below:

```
{
cout << "\t \t \t" << " O " << endl;
cout << "\t \t \t" << "/|\\" << endl;
cout << "\t \t \t" << " | " << endl;
cout << "\t \t \t" << "/ \\" << endl;
cout << " YOU ARE HUNG" endl;
return false; 
}
```

1 incorrect answer displays the head

2 incorrect answers displays the left arm

3 incorrect answers displays the right arm

4 incorrect answers displays the top half of the body

5 incorrect answers displays the bottom half of the body

6 incorrect answers displays the left leg

7 incorrect answers displays the right leg

My Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

bool is_hung(int, bool);

int main()
{
    string question1;
    string answer1;
    string answer2;
    string answer3;
    string answer4;
    string question2;
    string answer5;
    string answer6;
    string answer7;
    string answer8;
    string question3;
    string answer9;
    string answer10;
    string answer11;
    string answer12;
    string question4;
    string answer13;
    string answer14;
    string answer15;
    string answer16;
    string question5;
    string answer17;
    string answer18;
    string answer19;
    string answer20;
    string question6;
    string answer21;
    string answer22;
    string answer23;
    string answer24;
    string question7;
    string answer25;
    string answer26;
    string answer27;
    string answer28;
    string question8;
    string answer29;
    string answer30;
    string answer31;
    string answer32;

    ifstream reader;

    reader.open("infile.txt");

    int num_right = 0;
    int num_error = 0;
    bool power = true;
    cout << power << endl;
    string user_answer1 = "";
    string user_answer2 = "";
    string user_answer3 = "";
    string user_answer4 = "";
    string user_answer5 = "";
    string user_answer6 = "";
    string user_answer7 = "";
    string user_answer8 = "";

    while (power == true) {
        while (num_error < 7) //should stop the while loop when number of incorrect answers are equal to 7
        {
            //1
            getline(reader, question1); //get line from infile.txt
            getline(reader, answer1);
            getline(reader, answer2);
            getline(reader, answer3);
            getline(reader, answer4);
            cout << question1 << endl; //print out line from file
            cout << answer1 << endl;
            cout << answer2 << endl;
            cout << answer3 << endl;
            cout << answer4 << endl;
            cout << "Enter Answer: ";
            cin >> user_answer1; //have the user input answer
            if (user_answer1 == "B") //if statement to determine correct answer
            {
                cout << "correct" << endl;
                num_right++; //adds 1 to num_right
                cout << "" << endl;
            }
            else //if user_answer is not equal answer/wrong answer
            {
                cout << "incorrect" << endl;
                num_error++; //add 1 to num_error
                power = is_hung(num_error, power); //get function
            }
            //2
            getline(reader, question2);
            getline(reader, answer5);
            getline(reader, answer6);
            getline(reader, answer7);
            getline(reader, answer8);
            cout << question2 << endl;
            cout << answer5 << endl;
            cout << answer6 << endl;
            cout << answer7 << endl;
            cout << answer8 << endl;
            cout << "Enter Answer: ";
            cin >> user_answer2;
            if (user_answer2 == "B") {
                cout << "correct" << endl;
                num_right++;
                cout << "" << endl;
            }
            else {
                cout << "incorrect" << endl;
                num_error++;
                power = is_hung(num_error, power);
            }
            //3
            getline(reader, question3);
            getline(reader, answer9);
            getline(reader, answer10);
            getline(reader, answer11);
            getline(reader, answer12);
            cout << question3 << endl;
            cout << answer9 << endl;
            cout << answer10 << endl;
            cout << answer11 << endl;
            cout << answer12 << endl;
            cout << "Enter Answer: ";
            cin >> user_answer3;
            if (user_answer3 == "C") {
                cout << "correct" << endl;
                num_right++;
                cout << "" << endl;
            }
            else {
                cout << "incorrect" << endl;
                num_error++;
                power = is_hung(num_error, power);
            }
            //4
            getline(reader, question4);
            getline(reader, answer13);
            getline(reader, answer14);
            getline(reader, answer15);
            getline(reader, answer16);
            cout << question4 << endl;
            cout << answer13 << endl;
            cout << answer14 << endl;
            cout << answer15 << endl;
            cout << answer16 << endl;
            cout << "Enter Answer: ";
            cin >> user_answer4;
            if (user_answer4 == "D") {
                cout << "correct" << endl;
                num_right++;
                cout << "" << endl;
            }
            else {
                cout << "incorrect" << endl;
                num_error++;
                power = is_hung(num_error, power);
            }
            //5
            getline(reader, question5);
            getline(reader, answer17);
            getline(reader, answer18);
            getline(reader, answer19);
            getline(reader, answer20);
            cout << question5 << endl;
            cout << answer17 << endl;
            cout << answer18 << endl;
            cout << answer19 << endl;
            cout << answer20 << endl;
            cout << "Enter Answer: ";
            cin >> user_answer5;
            if (user_answer5 == "A") {
                cout << "correct" << endl;
                num_right++;
                cout << "" << endl;
            }
            else {
                cout << "incorrect" << endl;
                num_error++;
                power = is_hung(num_error, power);
            }
            //6
            getline(reader, question6);
            getline(reader, answer21);
            getline(reader, answer22);
            getline(reader, answer23);
            getline(reader, answer24);
            cout << question6 << endl;
            cout << answer21 << endl;
            cout << answer22 << endl;
            cout << answer23 << endl;
            cout << answer24 << endl;
            cout << "Enter Answer: ";
            cin >> user_answer6;
            if (user_answer6 == "D") {
                cout << "correct" << endl;
                num_right++;
                cout << "" << endl;
            }
            else {
                cout << "incorrect" << endl;
                num_error++;
                power = is_hung(num_error, power);
            }
            //7
            getline(reader, question7);
            getline(reader, answer25);
            getline(reader, answer26);
            getline(reader, answer27);
            getline(reader, answer28);
            cout << question7 << endl;
            cout << answer25 << endl;
            cout << answer26 << endl;
            cout << answer27 << endl;
            cout << answer28 << endl;
            cout << "Enter Answer: ";
            cin >> user_answer7;
            if (user_answer7 == "A") {
                cout << "correct" << endl;
                num_right++;
                cout << "" << endl;
            }
            else {
                cout << "incorrect" << endl;
                num_error++;
                power = is_hung(num_error, power);
            }
            cout << power << endl;
            //8
            getline(reader, question8);
            getline(reader, answer29);
            getline(reader, answer30);
            getline(reader, answer31);
            getline(reader, answer32);
            cout << question8 << endl;
            cout << answer29 << endl;
            cout << answer30 << endl;
            cout << answer31 << endl;
            cout << answer32 << endl;
            cout << "Enter Answer: ";
            cin >> user_answer8;
            if (user_answer8 == "D") {
                cout << "correct" << endl;
                num_right++;
                cout << "" << endl;
            }
            else {
                cout << "incorrect" << endl;
                num_error++;
                power = is_hung(num_error, power);
            }
            cout << "" << endl;
            if (num_error > 7) {
                cout << "You got " << num_right << " out of 8. You lose." << endl;
            }
            else if (num_error < 7) {
                cout << "You got " << num_right << " out of 8. You Win." << endl;
            }
            reader.close();
            return 0;
        }
    }
    reader.close();
    cout << "" << endl;
    if (num_error > 7) {
        cout << "You got " << num_right << " out of 16. You lose." << endl;
    }
    else if (num_error < 7) {
        cout << "You got " << num_right << " out of 16. You Win." << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

bool is_hung(int num_errors2, bool power2)
{
    if (num_errors2 == 1) {
        cout << "\t \t \t"
             << " O " << endl;
        cout << "" << endl;
        power2 = true;
        return power2;
    }
    else if (num_errors2 == 2) {
        cout << "\t \t \t"
             << " O " << endl;
        cout << "\t \t \t"
             << "/" << endl;
        cout << "" << endl;
        power2 = true;
        return power2;
    }
    else if (num_errors2 == 3) {
        cout << "\t \t \t"
             << " O " << endl;
        cout << "\t \t \t"
             << "/ \\" << endl;
        cout << "" << endl;
        power2 = true;
        return power2;
    }
    else if (num_errors2 == 4) {
        cout << "\t \t \t"
             << " O " << endl;
        cout << "\t \t \t"
             << "/|\\" << endl;
        cout << "" << endl;
        power2 = true;
        return power2;
    }
    else if (num_errors2 == 5) {
        cout << "\t \t \t"
             << " O " << endl;
        cout << "\t \t \t"
             << "/|\\" << endl;
        cout << "\t \t \t"
             << " | " << endl;
        cout << "" << endl;
        power2 = true;
        return power2;
    }
    else if (num_errors2 == 6) {
        cout << "\t \t \t"
             << " O " << endl;
        cout << "\t \t \t"
             << "/|\\" << endl;
        cout << "\t \t \t"
             << " | " << endl;
        cout << "\t \t \t"
             << "/ " << endl;
        cout << "" << endl;
        power2 = true;
        return power2;
    }
    else if (num_errors2 == 7) {
        cout << "\t \t \t"
             << " O " << endl;
        cout << "\t \t \t"
             << "/|\\" << endl;
        cout << "\t \t \t"
             << " | " << endl;
        cout << "\t \t \t"
             << "/ \\" << endl;
        cout << " YOU ARE HUNG" << endl;
        cout << "" << endl;
        power2 = false;
        return power2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's big old chunk of code. Can you please trim it down to a [mre]? It seems like this code does exactly the same thing 16 times. Using a vector of strings and a loop instead of manually enumerating all the variables would greatly improve the code.

Comment: @churill an array would be better than a vector

Comment: On a side note, there is no good reason to pass the `power` variable to the `is_hung()` function, since it is never being used.

Comment: you should reduce your code, there is a lot of repetition --> make use of a loop
you should use your debugger and go through the loop and wait until num errors hits 7 and see what happens

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, I think I know what you mean, indeed an array seems better suited here. Probably something like`std::string question; std::array<std::string, 6> answers; std::string userAnswer;` Then loop 16 times and reuse the variables.

Comment: I just want make it clear that I needed to have an entire file created for all those lines because my professor told me to. I would reduce this code if I was allowed to but my professor gave instructions on what functions to use.

Comment: @IsaiahSolomon that's .... strange, but shouldn't stop you from showing _us_ a [mre] with only a reasonable amount of code. Actually if this is the full task, I don't see any reason to not use a simple loop. Anyway, you need to break down the program and make it reproducible for us.

Comment: I'm new here so I don't really know the rules too well. I assuming you want me to cut it down to only the while loop. Won't my code stop functioning if I do that? I'll at least try to reduce it to 8 questions in the program because my code will have the same outcome with just that.

Comment: @IsaiahSolomon your instructor told you what functions to implement. I’m sure he didn’t tell you to implement them so much repetitive code, though.

Comment: @IsaiahSolomon check out the article I linked ;) You should cut down your code to a managable amount that still _runs_ and still _reproduces_ the error you get. Yes, that might mean to do a lot work on your part, but in many cases you will find the error in the process.

Answer (score 1):

There is a ridiculous amount of wasteful, repetitive code, which makes it extremely difficult to read and debug, and significantly increases the risk of making mistakes.

This code can be greatly reduced by making use of fewer variables, better loops, and a little arithmetic, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

bool is_hung(int);

int main()
{
    string question;
    string answer;
    string user_answer;

    const string correct_answers = “BBCDADADBDABCABB”;

    int num_right = 0;
    int num_error = 0;

    ifstream reader("infile.txt");

    for(int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
    {
        getline(reader, question); // get line from infile.txt
        cout << question << endl; // print out line from file
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
        {
            getline(reader, answer);
            cout << answer << endl;
        }
        cout << "Enter Answer: ";
        cin >> user_answer; // have the user input answer
        if (user_answer == correct_answers[i]) // if statement to determine correct answer
        {
            cout << "correct" << endl;
            num_right++; // adds 1 to num_right
            cout << endl;
        }
        else // if user_answer is not equal answer/wrong answer
        {
            cout << "incorrect" << endl;
            num_error++; // add 1 to num_error
            if (is_hung(num_error)) // get function
                break;
        }
    }

    reader.close();
    cout << endl;

    if (num_error == 7)
    {
        cout << "You got " << num_right << " out of 16. You lose." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "You got " << num_right << " out of 16. You Win." << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

bool is_hung(int num_errors)
{
    cout << "\t \t \t" << " O ";

    if (num_errors >= 2)
    {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "\t \t \t" << "/";
    }
    if (num_errors >= 3)
    {
        cout << (num_errors >= 4 ? ‘|’ : ‘ ‘) << “\\”;
    }
    if (num_errors >= 5)
    {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "\t \t \t" << " | ";
    }
    if (num_errors >= 6)
    {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "\t \t \t" << "/";
    }
    if (num_errors >= 7)
    {
        cout << " \\" << endl;
        cout << " YOU ARE HUNG";
    }

    cout << endl;
    return (num_errors < 7);
}
```

Don’t you think that is much easier to work with?